# Write18: LuaTeX has an encoding problem, where XeLaTeX does not

Tags: luatex, unicode, input-encodings, shell-escape

`xelatex` (with option `--shell-escape`) compiles this document fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
LuaTeX is not
\immediate\write18{echo uber | sed y/u/ü/ > inc.tex}
% or: \directlua{os.execute("echo uber | sed y/u/ü/ > inc.tex")}
\input{inc.tex}.
\end{document}
```

`lualatex` (with `--shell-escape`) returns this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: strings for `y' command are different lengths
```

Obviously LuaLaTeX has an encoding problem and treats “ü” as two characters, where XeLaTeX gets things fine. Is there any workaround?

Comment: In that particular case, I would try replacing `sed y/u/ü > inc.tex` by `sed s/u/ü/g > inc.tex`.

Comment: @Édouard Of course. I just gave a MWE, but in the real world the sed script is much more complex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LuaTeX resets the locale settings to C, the documentation says at the end of section "3.2 LUA changes":

> In stock LUA, many things depend on the current locale. In LUATEX, we
>   can’t do that, because it makes documents unportable. While LUATEX is
>   running if forces the following locale settings:
>
> ```
> LC_CTYPE=C
> LC_COLLATE=C
> LC_NUMERIC=C
> ```

Then `sed` does not see an Unicode character, encoded as UTF-8, but two bytes.

In case of `sed` the setting `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
LuaTeX is not
\immediate\write18{echo uber | env LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sed y/u/ü/ > inc.tex}
\input{inc.tex}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the change in settings revert to the original setting once the `sed` command is done, or is there a risk to change the behaviour of LuaTeX for the rest of the document?

Comment: I would guess that interpretation of the string is left entirely to the shell. The modified environment thus affects only the call to `sed` in this particular case. This can be checked by replacing the command by `echo uber | env LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 sed y/u/ü/ > inc.tex | locale`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: The environment variable is set via the program `env` that calls `sed` with the changed environment. Thus the setting is only valid for the called `sed` and its subprocesses. And without `env` the setting is only valid for the sub shell, which LuaTeX calls for the system command, and its subprocesses. But the environment of the parent process (LuaTeX) is not changed at all.